# Problem in Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate both of these integrals:

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[c x +  Sqrt[ b x + x^2] + a], x]
```

and

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[ x + c Sqrt[ b x + x^2] + a], x]
```

But *Mathematica* cannot calculate them while it can calculate

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[ x +  Sqrt[ b x + x^2] + a], x].
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to calculate these?

Even if I assign real numbers instead of $a,b$, and $c,$ *Mathematica* is not able to compute these integrals.

Thanks

Comment: Which values can `a`, `b` and `c` assume? If they are not arbitrary complex values, you can use the `Assumptions` option to give `Integrate` a hint, which might make the integral solvable.

Comment: even the Assumption option does not help. Mathematica cannot calculate the Integrate[1/Sqrt[c  x +  Sqrt[ b x + x^2] + a], x, 
 Assumptions -> {a, b, c} \[Element] Reals]

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but may serve as a pointer in the right direction. If you use [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/) to solve the 3rd example and look at the steps it takes to find the solution, you can observe that the first step is crucial:

[image: img]

To make it short, the condition that `e^2-c*f^2==0` is the problem for your first two examples. Look carefully at the expression in the transformation rule and then compare the coefficients. You will find that while the rule cannot be applied to `c x + Sqrt[...]` or `x + c Sqrt[...]`, the condition will hold for `c x + c Sqrt[...]` and therefore, both Mathematica and Rubi can solve

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[c x + c Sqrt[b x + x^2] + a], x]
```

Maybe this helps you, maybe it doesn't. Depending on how much you desire to solve this integral, it might be worth to talk to @AlbertRich in our [Gitter chatroom](https://gitter.im/Rule-Based-Integration/Lobby).

As a reference, I post the complete list of integration steps for the above integral

[image]